# Algorithm to Maximize Coverage, Minimize Item Usage?

Tags: algorithm

I've got a scenario that you can envision this way:

Start off with an image that is 100 pixels wide by 1000 pixels tall. 
In addition to that image, you have a set of cropped sections of that image. Each section is 100 pixels wide by 100 pixels tall. The part of the image contained in the section varies. For example, you might have one that starts at the very top (pixel 0), then one at vertical pixel 3, then one at vertical pixel 9 and so on.

What I need to do is find a way to look at those set of smaller pictures and pick out the smallest number of sections that would give me the most coverage of the original image.

A couple of notes:

1. The content of the image doesn't really matter. It's really matching up the coordinates that matters.
2. There will never be gaps in the image when reconstructed, but there *may* not be enough pieces to reach the bottom.
3. There will be a lot of overlap among the sections. In fact, there will be cases where there will be only a pixel or two of (vertical) difference between two sections.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I can do this sort of brute force... but I assume there's a better way.

Comment: @Tim, do the cropped sections overlap at all or are they unique?

Comment: They will definitely overlap. In fact, there will be a LOT of overlap, which is why trying to minimize the # of sections used is important.

Comment: @Tim, cool, so would it be OK if you take a greedy approach and take the cropped sections with the least amount of overlap?

Comment: This sounds very similar to the set cover problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), which is NP-hard. It's certainly a lot more structured than the general case, so I wouldn't be too surprised if an efficient solution exists. Plus you're interested in a bounded problem size, so asymptotic performance may not be an issue. But just something to keep in mind. It would be interesting to find a reduction...

Comment: @Tim, about how many cropped 100x100 sections are typical?

Comment: @Seth - for the example above, there could reasonably be 30-50 cropped sections. In some large ones (where the height extends to several thousand), it could get to 100-200. It's very very rarely going to get into the thousands.

Comment: @Lirik - I'm not even sure what the greedy approach to finding the least overlap would be in this case. Right now I've got an algorithm where I start at the beginning of a sorted set, move forward until there's a gap, then move back until its covered. Rinse, repeat. It works... but its not pretty.

Comment: @Tim, the Set Cover wikipedia page has the greedy algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm
 It says that you just take the set with the largest number of uncovered pixels until you cover all of them.

Comment: Is this really a 1D problem?  Are the "sections" always 100 pixels wide and hence covering the entire width?

Comment: @rrenaud - Yes, for now at least, its a 1D problem. Sections always cover the widths. I may expand what I'm working on in the future to be 2D, but for now 1D works.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why the votes to close and the downvotes? I'm not complaining, just wondering what I can do to ask a better question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I fail to see why this problem is NP-hard.

The general idea is that you'll remove iteratively bottom parts of your image by selecting the "best" section, that is

- The biggest section that covers the bottom of the image
- If you fail finding one (because no section covers the last line of pixels) just take the one closest to the bottom.
- Rinse and repeat

Begin by sorting the sections. You'll get something like (0,1,3,10,...,988,999) where 0 corresponds to a section that begins at the top pixel. (And the one corresponding to 999 covers only one line)

Suppose your original image is 100xN. Initially, N=1000.

Let n be the index of the image that best covers the end of the original image :  i.e n is the smallest number in that list such that n+100>=N. If there is no such number, n is simply the biggest number.

If your sorted list is (0,1,...899, 900, 901,..,999) then n=900

If your sorted list is (0,1,...899, 905, 910,..,999) then n=905

If your sorted list is (0,1,...,888,898,) then n=898

Then start again with N=n (you've removed a part of the bottom of the original image) (of course, remove from the sorted list all the sections that are ">=n")

I think that setting fixed-height sections (100 pixels) removes the NP-hardness.

Comment: This pretty closely aligns with how I ended up implementing it on my first cut, except for one point: I don't (necessarily) know what the "end" is until I've been through the whole list. So I start at the beginning and work forward (actually forward and back, forward and back).

Comment: It's not NP-complete even if you get rid of the restriction on N.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer since it ends up being the closest thing to what I ended up doing anyway. A lot of this algorithm talk is a little over my head, but I wanted to give credit to someone because of everyone's hard work on this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem -- The elements of the sets are pixels (you can write the code such that it doesn't deal with things pixel-by-pixel).

Because it is 100x1000, the problem is no longer NP-hard, probably in P even. A greedy approach will not work, but there exists a dynamic programming solution as follows, which works roughly in `O(N)` time if sufficiently spread out, otherwise `O(N * max_overlap_#)`. The trick is to go "forwards and backwards".

```
input:
    [                        ] to fill
    [  (]  )  { ([}) ]  ( [) ]
return:
    Result set of squares which maximize cover, secondarily
     minimizing the size of the Result set if covered areas are equal

the score of the leftmost element is {area:100^2, num:1}
for each square S in order, left->right:
    (Assuming you pick S in Result...)
    let Candidates = {all squares which overlap S and are left of S}
                     + {first non-overlapping square left of S}
    for each candidate C:
        let score(S) = score(C) + {area:new_area_covered_by_S, num:1}
        pick candidate BestC which maximizes score(S)
        draw a line between S and BestC

Take the square with the best score, and work your way backwards
 along the chain of best-picks, returning only those squares.
```

This assumes you will add an extra square even for an extra 0.0001% coverage, i.e. "at every point, if it is possible to cover it with a square, it must be covered with a square". You can modify this algorithm though to trade off appropriately.

This further assumes it is not the case that nearly all the squares are overlapping each other at a single point (they are somewhat spread out but may still overlap); otherwise it may take a long time.

Also note that you may divide the problem into subproblems whenever you have a break that is unfilled by a square.

Comment: The OPs problem is not NP-complete because he isn't covering by general sets, but rather by intervals, which are much, much more structured and less interesting that arbitrary sets.  We can exploit the structure of intervals to give a fast algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This exact problem is covered by [algorithmist](http://algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_10020).

A greedy [sweep line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) style algorithm algorithm  will solve your problem optimally.

Assuming you want to first cover as much non-disjoint area as possible, and secondarily use the fewest number sections given the first constraint, then this algorithm will solve the problem for you in O(n^2) time.

The basic idea is to go in order from top to bottom, and only take a section when you are 'naked', that is, have not covered the given section.  When you are forced to take a section, take the one that will cover you most into the 'future'.  This implementation is O(n^2), but you can make it O(n log(n)) by managing the cands a bit better.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

START_EVENT, END_EVENT = 0, 1  # handle starts before ends at same point

def max_future(cands):
  return max(cands, key=lambda c: (c[1], c)[1])

def cover_max_segment_min(intervals):
  events = []
  for interval in intervals:
    events.append((interval[0], START_EVENT, interval))
    events.append((interval[1], END_EVENT, interval))
  cands = []
  outputs = []
  alive = None
  # Handle events by 
  #   event time, 
  #   starts before ends, 
  #   longer endings before shorter endings
  events.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1], -x[2][1]))
  for k, event_type, interval in events:
    if event_type == START_EVENT:
        cands.append(interval)
    if event_type == END_EVENT:
        cands.remove(interval)
        if interval is alive:
            alive = None
    if not alive and cands:
        outputs.append(max_future(cands))
        alive = outputs[-1]
  return outputs

assert cover_max_segment_min([(0, 3), (1, 4), (3, 5)]) == \
   [(0, 3), (3, 5)]
assert cover_max_segment_min([(0, 3), (3, 5), (1, 4)]) == \
   [(0, 3), (3, 5)]
assert cover_max_segment_min([(0, 3)]) == [(0, 3)]
assert cover_max_segment_min([]) == []
assert cover_max_segment_min([(-10, 10), (1, 2), (3, 5)]) == [(-10, 10)]
assert cover_max_segment_min([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]) == \
   [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
assert cover_max_segment_min([(1, 4), (1, 2), (3, 3)]) == \
   [(1, 4)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot believe the claim that this will solve the problem optimally. It is an NP-hard problem, and probably still a difficult problem even if we only use fixed-sized squares. This is not to say that a greedy approach should not be used or will not yield good results. But to claim that it will solve the problem optimally unfortunately doesn't work. For example, this particular greedy algorithm would, as stated, pick all rectangles in the situation of: `[   A{  ](B }C   )`, rather than just the minimum required of A and C.

Comment: 3SAT is NP complete.  2 SAT is a subset of 3SAT.  I can give you a fast, optimal algorithm for 2SAT.  I think the [(0, 3), (1, 4), (3, 5)] example is isomorphic to your test case.  My psuedo code was buggy, I fixed it and it works on your test case.